# Delay in opening combobox when using an item renderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to figure out a way to improve the performance of a combobox with an item render in it.  When I use a combobox without a custom item renderer the drop down opens quickly and the combobox is very responsive. When I add a simple item renderer it now takes a second before opening the combobox. It's like its creating all the children and then caching them. After that the combobox opens fine, until you select an item. Then opening the combobox takes a while again too.

Here is a sample application that demonstrates the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            height="100%" width="100%" xmlns:local="*"
    >
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
               [{label:"test1"}, 
                {label:"test2"}, 
                {label:"test3"}]);

    ]]></mx:Script>

<!-- combobox with item renderer, this has a delay when opening -->

<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
                <mx:Label text="'item renderer' + {data.label}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:ComboBox>

<!-- default combobox, this works fine -->

<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

What am I missing here? It doesn't seem like this should be happening.

Comment: This won't help you, but I didn't notice any performance issues with the above app compiled with the Flex 4.6 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, good to know.  Unfortunately I can't upgrade the SDK, I'm stuck using Flex 3.5 for this application.  This may be a bug in flex for all I know and it was addressed in Flex 4.

Comment: I'll also clarify that you cannot use a ComboBox w/o an itemRenderer.  You probably meant you were using the ComboBox w/ the default itemRenderer.

Comment: Yes, the default renderer. Thanks.

Comment: I made an edit to clarify I'm using a custom item renderer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time trying to find a solution, what I found is if there is only one "clean" child component gets defined in `<mx:Component>`, the performance will be much better.

So the following gives good performance:

```
<mx:Component>
    <mx:HBox /> ( "clean" )
</mx:Component>
```

and this one gives bad performance (the delay):

```
<mx:Component>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label /> ( not "clean" )
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Component>
```

To solve this problem, we can create the child components by using codes:

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
            <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import mx.controls.Label;

                    // Define the label instance
                    private var lbl:Label = new Label();

                    // Add the label as a child component
                    override protected function createChildren(): void {
                        super.createChildren();
                        addChild( lbl );
                    }

                    // Set the data
                    override public function set data( value:Object ): void {
                        super.data = value;
                        if ( value ) {
                            lbl.text = value.label;
                        }
                    }
                ]]>
            </mx:Script>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

Demo: https://github.com/jeantimex/flex-combobox-itemrenderer

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting observation, I'm still curious as to why this is such an issue with flex 3.5 but at least I'm not crazy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may be a step in the right direction; but I can't guarantee a solution.  I suggest you start by re-writing your itemRenderer not to use binding.  I've solved a lot of memory leaks for paying clients by teaching them that.  Binding is also known to be a performance heavy operation in itemRenderers; so I would recommend that it get removed from the operation.

Instead of using Binding in an itemRenderer, I prefer to respond to the dataChange method.

I also recommend that you remove the HBox from your itemRenderer; as you should be able to use the label as is:

```
<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:Label dataChange="onDataChange(event)">
              <mx:Script>
                 protected function onDataChange(event:Event):void{
                    this.text='item renderer' + data.label;
                 }
              </mx:Script>
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:ComboBox>
```

I'm not sure if that will address any performance issues.  There are a  lot of oddities w/ the Flex ComboBox that I've had to work through while creating the Flextras AutoComplete.

Memory tells me that in Flex 3.4 (and before) every time the drop down was closed; it was destroyed--essentially not cached in memory.  This changed in Flex 3.5 whereas they started caching it and re-using the same drop down object.  I wonder if your perceived performance issues are related to that somehow.

---

Edit 1:
Based on complaints about this post not addressing the underlying issue; I put together [this test case](http://www.flextras.com/labs/forclients/fordevshorts/ComboBox_SO.html) based on the original posters code and my suggested changes.  My suggested changes do indeed solve the issue the original poster was having.  Here is the source behind the sample:

```
    [Bindable]
    public var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
        [{label:"test1"}, 
            {label:"test2"}, 
            {label:"test3"}]);

]]></mx:Script>

<!-- combobox with item renderer, this has a delay when opening -->

<mx:VBox>

<!-- ComboBox provided by original poster -->
<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
                <mx:Label text="'item renderer' + {data.label}"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:ComboBox>


<!-- ComboBox with rewritten itemRenderer; which does not exhibit the problem -->
<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
            <mx:Label dataChange="label1_dataChangeHandler(event)">
                <mx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                        protected function label1_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                        {
                            this.text = "item renderer" + data.label;
                        }

                    ]]>
                </mx:Script>
            </mx:Label>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:ComboBox>


<!-- default combobox, this works fine -->

<mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

---

Edit 2:
devshorts says my code does not work if we create the component as a stand alone itemRenderer; however I don't understand why not.

Here is the code for the stand alone itemRenderer, named com.flextras.listRenderers.CustomLabelRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" dataChange="label1_dataChangeHandler(event)">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function label1_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.text = "item renderer" + data.label;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>    
</mx:Label>
```

And here is some code to add to the mail application above to test it:

```
<!-- ComboBox, like above with the itemRenderer as a separate component -->
    <mx:ComboBox width="200"
             dataProvider="{dataProvider}" itemRenderer="com.flextras.listRenderers.CustomLabelRenderer" />
```

I updated the [application at my provided link](http://www.flextras.com/labs/forclients/fordevshorts/ComboBox_SO.html) to include this new ComboBox instance; it is now the 3rd on the list.

Comment: Your suggestions on an obvious sample app not-withstanding (excess nesting in a 5 line app, the post isn't about memory leaks so binding isn't an issue, etc), what is interesting is your suggestion about the destroying/recreating.  However, it doesn't really explain why when you use the default renderer (even with icons) it doesn't have the peformance drop.  Especially since I'm using Flex 3.5 already.

Comment: It is "common knowledge" that Binding can cause both Memory Leaks and performance problems.  As I understood it; In Bindable classes, for example, one change can cause bindings to be recalculated for every property; which can be a costly operation.  I don't know if that is what is going on here, though.  Memory Leaks can lead to performance problems.  I'd say the same for extra nesting.  sine the issue only exists w/ your custom renderer; I would suspect the issue is with that renderer and not an inherent Flex issue.

Comment: Because its not addressing the actual issue. You pointed out a bunch of trivia that is not pertinent about a sample application that was meant only to act as an illustration to the issue. While what you said is correct, its missing the topic completely, which is why I downvoted you.

Comment: @devshorts I have modified my answer in order to include a full runnable sample that proves my suggested changes do indeed solve the issue you are trying to address.  Try it out "live" here: http://www.flextras.com/labs/forclients/fordevshorts/ComboBox_SO.html The first comboBox is the one provided in the question; the second is one w/ my itemRenderer edit; and the third is the default.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately this doesn't translate to any kind of production level code.  Nobody is actually relying on a simple label like this nor using an inline item renderer.  On top of that, move your item renderer as is into a seperate mxml component and reference it as the item renderer for a combobox you'll see that it still exhibits the problem.  On top of that, if you move your code into a seperate item renderer you no longer get any values for the combobox anyways. Even if you hinge on the item renderers dataChange event you will still get the stickiness of the combobox.

Comment: I don't understand "if you move your code into a seperate item renderer you no longer get any values for the combobox anyways" I don't understand what values you are not getting.  To say that itemRenderers have to use Binding to display values is incorrect.  I'll have to try it with the non-inline renderer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15907/discussion-between-devshorts-and-www-flextras-com)

Comment: Chat is timing out for the moment; but I just wanted to say that I update my answer to demonstrate using a separate class as an itemRenderer.  My updated code is not exhibiting the delay that the originally provided code was.